# How to set a bytes field using the python protobuf 2.5.0?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

Having a message

```
message MyMessage {
  required bytes mybytesfield = 1;
}
```

I generated the python code with

```
protoc -I. --python_out=. message.proto
```

and try to add the bytes field like this (Python 2.7.6):

```
import message_pb2 as mpb

msg = mpb.MyMessage()
msg.mybytesfield = bytes([0xDE, 0xAD])
# msg.mybytesfield = b'\xDE\xAD'
with open("output.bin", "w") as f:
    f.write(msg.SerializeToString())
```

but it seems to encode the literal `[222, 173]` instead of `dead` judging from the output of `hexdump -C`.

What is the correct way to write `0xDEAD` into the `mybytesfield`?

Answer (score 3):

`bytes([0xDE, 0xAD])` doesn't translate to `b'\xde\xad'` in Python 2.7 but to `'[222, 123]'` that is a string of 10 characters that is the string representation of the array.

`bytes` in Python 2.7 is an alias of `str`, in Python 3.x `bytes` does the "expected" thing and `bytes([0xde, 0xad])` yields `b'\xde\xad`.

The correct way to set the `mybytesfield` is the following:

```
msg.mybytesfield = b'\xDE\xAD' #literal
```

or if you need had a list/array of integers in the first place:

```
msg.mybytesfield = ''.join(chr(item) for item in [0xDE, 0xAD])
```